# Time frame for PR application with job offer for Canada

Tags: working-visas, canada, resident-permit, express-entry

I have an express entry profile with 435 points. Now I have received a job offer. The company said they can arrange a working visa (2years) and that they can help apply for PR once I started working. Without waiting for that, with the offer letter I have, can I apply for PR myself? If that's not possible, how long will it take to get the PR when I start working in Canada?

Comment: Just wondering what research you have already done?

Comment: CIC page said processing time is 45 days. But my hiring manager mentioned that it could be done within 2 years. So I'm kind of confused

Comment: I would interpret that as two years’ qualifying period, 45 days to process once the qualifying period is over and you can apply

Comment: Can I not apply myself through the express entry pool? People who get through them get the PR and move to Canada right?

Comment: The government says to expect about 6 months processing time after you submit your application after you get an ITA. 45 days are if your are submitting a PR application after being in Canada.

Comment: @mkennedy in my case, where I'll apply from Canada with a job offer, as the draws happen every month, can I expect to get it in 6 months time?